# How to send multicast message (multiple users) using xmpphp and PHP

Tags: php, xmpphp

I want to send multicast message to other users in ejabbered.

I have succeeded in send 'single' and 'group' message

> //for single chat

```
$conn->message($toJabberId, $message, "chat", null, null);
```

> //for group chat

```
$conn->presence(NULL, "available", $nickname);
$conn->message($chatroom, $message, "groupchat", null, null);
$conn->presence(NULL, "unavailable", $nickname);
```

And now i am trying to incorporte multicast facility in my code. Actually i have following sample stanza for multicast but don't know to use in xmpphp.

```
<message to='multicast.jabber.org'>
   <addresses xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/address'>
       <address type='to' jid='hildjj@jabber.org/Work' desc='Joe Hildebrand'/>
       <address type='cc' jid='jer@jabber.org/Home' desc='Jeremie Miller'/>
   </addresses>
   <body>Hello, world!</body>
</message>
```

Any idea to multicast message using xmpphp?

Thanks.